# Fetch the time between two timestamps in R

Tags: sql, r, timestamp, dplyr, rsqlite

Please run the code below: The "patients$time" column gives the timestamp. I want to fetch all the records between two times say first row value "2017-01-02 11:41:53" and 226th row value "2017-08-07 09:06:07". I want to basically get all the records between these two times. I tried dbGetquery but am getting an error. Please help.

```
library(bupaR)
patients
```

[image]

Comment: does this work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
patients[patients$time > '2017-01-02 11:41:53' & patients$time < '2017-08-07 09:06:07',]
```

Comment: the solution is very helpful thanks, but suppose I am fetching data from a database where billions of records are present, I wanted a functionality in R and sql such that I fetch the subset of the data only to make the solution faster. Please help.

Comment: your question is incorrect, you present a dataframe and expect to give a dbquery answer?

Comment: the question is correct, still I find your solution helpful, thanks.